# onClick function programmed for an ecmascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of data in my html file that is loaded on page load. There is a bunch of graph data that populates the page and slows down page load. I want this information to only load once the  play button is pressed.

This is how it starts within the page...

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    <![CDATA[

var refresh_timeout;

/**
 * getURL is a proprietary Adobe function, but it's simplicity has made it very
 * popular. If getURL is undefined we spin our own by wrapping XMLHttpRequest.
 */
if (typeof getURL == 'undefined') {
  getURL = function(url, callback)....
.
.
.
.
```

Now, I have this block of code that applies the information I need, but I want this ecmascript to be programmed to the onClick function that lies within the block below.

```
<div class="box-content" style="overflow-x: hidden; padding-top: 0; position: relative; height: 400px;">
    <div class="dim-wrapper">
        <div class="dim-overlay">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-transparent text-large" onclick="loadBandwidthData()" style="line-height: 0;"><i class="icon icon-play-circle"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Why ECMAscript instead of just JavaScript?

Comment: I guess this is how the previous developer left it. Maybe because of all the SVG stuff? I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you tried it without specifying the type? Does it still work?

Comment: I mean, it lies within the middle of the html page, wouldn't that specification be required?

Comment: I tried just wrapping everything in the script type inside of a function, but it seems to break stuff.

Comment: `seems to break stuff` is meaningless without some error output context. Check your console

Comment: I mean, there is no error. It's just that without wrapped, the data loads and if it is wrapped in a function, the data does not load on click. I do know that the button is working though.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in JSFiddle? It'll be easier for us to test.